# How to give non id WHERE condition in sphinx search source conf for indexing mysql table

Tags: sphinx

I am currently indexing a mysql table using sphinx. I want the index by giving a condition in query apart from id.

My **sql_query** is

```
SELECT id, group_id, concat(ifnull(title, ""), ifnull(tags, "")) \
                FROM items \
                 WHERE group_id in (262, 147, 165, 190, 256, 272, 442, 577, 933) and id>=$start AND id<=$end;
```

My **sql_info** is

```
SELECT id, concat(ifnull(title, ""), ifnull(tags, "")) FROM items WHERE group_id in (262, 147, 165, 190, 256, 272, 442, 577, 933) and id=$id;
```

But, when I try to index the table using there queries, the index fails.
1) Am I missing anything in the above queries.?
2) How do I index queries by giving conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you should give an alias to your compound text statement, sphinx might well choke on trying to create an *field* called `concat(ifnull(title, ""), ifnull(tags, ""))`.

```
SELECT id, group_id, concat(ifnull(title, ""), ifnull(tags, "")) AS text \
```